# Does inputstream contain data of iframe?

Tags: java, url, iframe, inputstream, httpurlconnection

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/iframe-pdf.html");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
```

When calling on getInputStream, i turn all the bytes into a string. But why am i not seeing any sign of the data in the iframe?

My goal is to download the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

If you request a URL, you will only get the contents of that file.  An iframe is normally effectively a seperate page, so you would need to request that seperately.  A browser will normally do all this transparently.

I would recommend using a library such as JSoup which contains lots of methods for parsing HTML, which you will need to get the URL of the iframe (and the URL of the PDF).